# How do I evaluate a javascript variable when web scrapping using cheerio

Tags: javascript

When I used Cheerio to scrape https://www.bankofamerica.com/home-equity/assumptions-home-equity/?loanType=homeEquity&state=CA, I only receive a variable name instead of the variable value.

Code:

```js
const BankofAmericaScraper = async (browser) => {
  const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(URL, {
    waitUntil: ["load"],
    timeout: 0,
  });
  const MortgagesPage = await page.content();
  const $ = cheerio.load(MortgagesPage);
  const step1 = Object.values($(".col-num-2")[2])[5];
}
```

I get `{{ percentage rates.product.currentRate }}` and not `6.650`.
How do I access the variable? I'm using a headless browser to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: With Cheerio, **you cant**

So right off the bat, Cheerio documentation states

> Cheerio parses markup and provides an API for traversing/manipulating
> the resulting data structure. **It does not** interpret the result as a
> web browser does. Specifically, it does not produce a visual
> rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or **execute JavaScript**

The trade off for this is having that speed of returning data, in comparison to other libraries that emulate the page.